# How close must a full moon be to become a supermoon?

Tags: terminology, the-moon, definition

According to [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/19080/7156) there is a scale of super moons depending on how close the full moon(henceforth anti-sol) is to perigee. So how close to anti-sol does the moon's perigee need to be to be referred to as a "super moon"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermoon#Terminology explains the term isn't well-defined among astronomers, and is actually astrological in origin. Of course, I didn't check the sources and wikipedia can always be wrong :)